# Resultant JSON from ObjectMapper contains invisible dot "."

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am using

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Estimate)
```

which results to:

> { "estimate":{
> "big":1,
> "mid":1,
> "small":1 }".​"}

the above '.' is basically some garbage chars(â€‹) which is not visible normally but if I use some JSON formatter there it says the JSON is invalid and shows the dot like this:
[image]

normally when I see the JSON in note pad it shows up like this clean with no anomaly. and it should actually be like this only without any invalid hidden char.

> { "estimate":{ "big":1, "mid":1, "small":1 }"}

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show full code. How do you print result of `writeValueAsString` ?

Comment: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(new Estimate("1","2")));

Comment: @ekiryuhin I am not printing the result actually, sending that as Kafka message.